# What's the best way to merge or parent these?

Tags: parent, collections

So for context, I'm new to blender and making a simple building structure. I am going to add at least one more object to it.
[image]

How can I put all of these "plane"s into a collection while keeping their children, or combine them all into one object?

Comment: To Join all of these: select them all (perhaps by Select >> Pattern >> "Plane*",  Then Object >> Join.

Comment: To move into a Collection: select them all (perhaps by Select >> Pattern >> "Plane*", 'm' (move to collection) (or Object >> Collection >> Move to Collection, and either select an existing collection or "create new collection".